# Scheme word translator "In procedure cadr: Wrong type (expecting pair): #f"

Tags: scheme

I want to build a word translator in Scheme. I have to use Scheme only. So far the base of my code looks like this:

```
(define data '((hallo hello)
               (apfel apple)
               (welt world)))


(map (lambda (i) (display (cadr (assoc i data)))) (list "hallo" "apfel" "welt"))
```

After I tried to run it the error "In procedure cadr: Wrong type (expecting pair): #f" occured.

It should display the translation of each element of the list data.

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary is a list of symbols, but your input is a list of strings - they're different data types, so `assoc` doesn't find them. You should consider the case when the word is not found (`assoc` returns `#f`, this explains the error you're getting). And don't use `display` to return results in a list. Try this for starters:

```
(define data '((hallo hello)
               (apfel apple)
               (welt world)))

(map (lambda (i) (cadr (assoc i data)))
     '(hallo apfel welt))
=> '(hello apple world)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a note that `(assoc bad-value alist)` returns `#f` and trying to call `(cadr #f)` breaking down your program. Let's try to add some improvements to your program. At first step you need `reduce` function:

```
  (if (null? lst) init-value
      (fn (car lst)
          (reduce fn init-value (cdr lst)))))
```

save it to your `utils.scm`, you will need it every day to work, teach and so on. And now you can just fold/reduce yout data alist:

```
(define *data*
  '((hallo hello)
    (apfel apple)
    (welt world)))

(reduce (λ (item acc)
          (let ((found-pair (assoc item *data*)))
            (if found-pair
                (cons (cadr found-pair) acc)
                acc)))
        '()
        '(hatllo ; bad value
          apfel  ; good value
          welt   ; good value
          ))
;; result ==> '(apple world)
```

It works fine, but! It's not enough. Perfectly you need to remove every founded value from *data* but not destroy the *data*. Conclusing, the solution above is fast prototype. Take this idea and improve it.